# Each time I view a php page on localhost, it downloads the page

Tags: php

I have altered the httpd.conf file good to my knowledge by adding index.php in the directory index,

```
LoadModule php5_module "d:/php/php5apache2_2.dll"
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
    PHPIniDir "d:/php"
```

But any .php file I load, it downloads it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks
Jean

Comment: is your apache service running?

Comment: Did you restart Apache server after adding these lines to httpd.conf?

Comment: how do you load the php file? Are the folder/file permissions set to executable?

Comment: @ken restarted, does not restart

Comment: What set-up are you using? Sounds like Apache isn't running.

Comment: @gordon put the file in d:\php\

Comment: @Jean that doesnt answer my question. You say when you load the file, it downloads it, so what are the steps you take to load the file? With what do you load it? And how? And does the directory have proper permissions?

Comment: http://localhost/index.php.  The browser downloads the file as if, I am downloading a .exe.

Comment: @Martin: If Apache wasn't running, OP would be getting "connection refused", not a file download.

Comment: @Marc B Not really, because there wouldn't be a server to refuse the connection. In Windows, if a PHP script is requested in a web browser from the user's local file system, then they will be prompted with a download dialog.

Comment: True, but then they'd have to be requesting `c:\foo\bar.php`, and not `localhost/foo/bar.php`.

Comment: @Jean, you say that you "restarted, it does not restart." If you mean that Apache will not restart then you have to get that going first. After that, one obscure thing to check is whether the browser is set to always download that file type. You might have set this by accident at some point. For example, in FireFox, go to Tools then Options, click on Applications, and when the list comes up find "application/x-httpd-php". Make sure it says "Always ask" or the equivalent for your browser, and not "Save file."

Comment: @RobertB, PHP should not send the application/x-httpd-php content-type to the browser. It defaults to text/html. Browser should not be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

The browser is not the issue - it is something with your configuration. Where have you placed this code in your httpd.conf file? Is it nested within other (perhaps module-specific) code? Maybe you can provide more (or all) of your http.conf file, and anything relevant in apache's startup log.

If you're not familiar with configuring apache, you may want to consider using a distribution of LAMP/WAMP as those will work out of the box.

But there is definitely something wrong with your apache configuration. For one reason or another (in apache's config), your PHP is not being parsed. This could be because the PHP isn't installed properly, because you've put the code to enable it in the wrong spot where it isn't being invoked, because you need something more than that for your specific environment, or because you have something conflicting with the code.